# Harry Potter FanFiction where Harry changes his name to Peverell

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I do not remember much about this work, as it’s been a year or two since I read it but this is what I remember:

- Harry has a sibling
- It’s one of those Harry Potter fics where his parents neglect him
- Wrong Boy-Who-Lived
- Harry is the oldest, and is entitled to the Potter Lordship
- Harry hears James talking about giving it to his sibling?
- Harry takes on the name Peverell/Claims Peverell Lordship; and because of this, it means he’s above James in the rankings? Like, this is due to the fact that the Potters stem from the Peverells
- Harry can take/blast James (or did take/blast James) front he family tree due to his status as a Peverell
- I feel like he was originally Harry then changed his name or Hadrian/Harrison or some form of Harry
- Definitely on FanFiction.net

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this might be BloodRedDemon's "[Feral](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10831723/1/Feral)"

> Neglected in favour of his younger brother, Harry Potter always was dissatisfied. His Parents and their friends fawned over Thomas, no matter what the older brother did. Harry upped and left; why would he have stayed? 6 years later, Harry Potter found a new home. The boy is in the middle of it all, though. What will his role be? Where will his allegiance lie?

From [Chapter 11](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10831723/11/Feral):

> "Henry 'Harry' James Potter," Ragnok began, in a rasp. Why Henry was shortened to Harry, Harry would never know. "Heir to the house of Potter," Why would he announce that. "Heir apparent to the house of Black," Harry's eyes widened at this, nobody had told him anything about being named heir to Sirius if he died without a legitimate heir. Harry would bet that he had at least one illegitimate. Thomas, meanwhile, was a mixture of gobsmacked and furious. How dare Sirius name his arsehole of an older brother heir and not him?! "Now named Lord of houses..." The goblin took a gulp, as Harry's face paled considerably. He wasn't even 17! How could he be a *Lord*? Not to mention the fact that his fucking father was still alive! "Peverell," Harry vaguely remembered a bedtime story about the three brothers. That would just be a title though, right? They were around eons ago, Peverell couldn't hold any seats on the Wizengamot or anything, could they? "And..." The goblin's hands were *shaking*! The head of Gringotts, for crying out loud! Oddly, he was interrupted by his fellow.